# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage.filters._sparse_cy'

Tags: python, pycharm, scikit-image

when i use the fuction skimage.feature.greycomatrix,
pycharm error:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage.filters._sparse_cy'`,
the version of skimage: 0.18.1
Code:

```
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
import cv2
img_org = cv2.imread('train_video/frame/tr_123.jpg')
result = skimage.feature.greycomatrix(img_org, [1], [0, np.pi/2], levels=4)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/thomas/py_code/test_4.py", line 7, in
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\feature_init_.py", line 3, in
from .canny import canny
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\feature_canny.py", line 18, in
from ..filters import gaussian
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters_init.py", line 12, in
from .thresholding import (threshold_local, threshold_otsu, threshold_yen,
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\thresholding.py", line 14, in
from ._sparse import correlate_sparse, _validate_window_size
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters_sparse.py", line 2, in
from ._sparse_cy import _correlate_sparse_offsets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage.filters._sparse_cy'
```

Answer (score 0):

- there is a [github issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5215#issuecomment-772032605) which can help you.
- install the binary compiled Lib from: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image)